# Ioticism in Greek

Tags: vowels, greek, sound-change, diachronic, vowel-height

Are there any good theories about what motivated the pervasive [ioticism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iotacism) that developed between ancient Greek and modern Greek?  Are there any other languages that went through analogous changes?

The first domino seems to have been the fronting of ypsilon from /u/ to /y/ in Attic Greek, but why would that unbalance the whole system in this particular way or why would this be a leading indicator of some other shift in the vowel system?  Is there some feature all the old vowels had in common?

The only somewhat analogous case I can think of is how many many short vowels in Sanskrit shifted to /a/; however, I would think that pronouncing more of this vowel would at least result in less muscular effort.  Are there better analogies?

Comment: I'm not sure the fronting of /u/ is really relevant -- that's a much older change, and as you say it's hard to see why it would lead to the other changes. There may not be a better answer than that [y] > [i] and [e] > [i] are both common sound changes, and there happened to be some earlier mergers that fed into those.

Comment: Larry Trask's _Historical Linguistics_ has a discussion of the complete system and its development on pp 88-90.

Comment: Iotacism is quite common in Bavarian German as well, e.g. München ⟶ Minchen, in Yiddish, etc; it is not an outlier phenomenon. It may not be complete in dialects of Modern Greek (κιούρτος, άγκιουρα, κουτί, μουστάκι, τρούπα, τσουλώ, κουμάσι).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mergers to /i/ are not uncommon in general. The asymmetrical development of η, ει, ω, ου to [i, i, o, u] reminds me of how Middle English /ɛː/ /eː/ /ɔː/ /oː/ become early modern English [iː, iː, oː, uː].

In fact, English has merged many different Old English vowels to /i/ (the *fleece* vowel, also written /iː/): Old English *ē* /eː/, *ǣ* /æː/, *ēa* /æːɑ̯/ (or /æə/, depending on the analyst) and in some cases *e* /e/.

Latin also shows a similar development of its native diphthong *ei* to /iː/.